# com.datastax.driver.core.OperationTimedOutException

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I created the following test class using Cassandra.

```
private static String server_ip = "127.0.0.1";
private static String keyspace = "hr";

private static Cluster cluster = null;
private static Session session = null;

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    if(cluster!=null) return;

    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(server_ip).withPort(9042).build();


    final Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    String msg = String.format("Connected to cluster: %s", metadata.getClusterName());
    System.out.println(msg);

    System.out.println("List of hosts");
    for (final Host host : metadata.getAllHosts())
    {
        msg = String.format("Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s",
        host.getDatacenter(),
        host.getAddress(),
        host.getRack());
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
}
```

(Cluster.java:407)
    at samples.SampleB.main(SampleB.java:28)

After googling, I try all the proposing solution without success. Could you please help me solving this issue?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Verify that the cassandra is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should verify those dependencies:

```html
<!-- Apache Cassandra Datastax's CQL driver. -->
 
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks @Saria for your help. You save my life.